# Typescript 1.0 RequireJS Plugin

Tags: requirejs, typescript

I'm looking for a RequireJS plugin that supports loading Typescript 1.0 code.

I found https://github.com/iammerrick/require-ts, but it seems to only work with an older version of Typescript and has not been updated in a long time.

Answer (score 2):

Please don't. Run JS in the browser. Reason:

`import dep = require('./something');`

is easier + more typesafe than:

```
define(['ts!./something'], function(dep) {
  // dep is compiled to JS at this point.
});
```

Perhaps you are unaware of [TypeScript external modules.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDrWLMUY0R0&hd=1)

Comment: +1 - TypeScript was designed to load external modules, so just use it without plugins and you'll have what you want.

Comment: This isn't helpful. I have an existing project that uses RequireJS with hundreds of files. I can't just convert everything to Typescript; I have to go one file at a time.

Comment: @noah agreed. Even for that you can still compile the "new" ts to js and load it in the js